# Beautifulsoup giving me None value rather than Text exits in HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation, beautifulsoup, bots

I'm making a Bot for Upwork.com so I want to get "posted time" of Upwork post as you can see below

[image: screenshot]

But when I get a text it returns a None value

I'm using this code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request('https://www.upwork.com/o/jobs/browse/?q=scrap', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html = urlopen(req).read()
soup = beautifulsoup(html)
for all_items in soup.select('.job-tile'):
    Time=all_items.select_one('time').text
    print(Time)
```

output:

```
None
```

when i get HTML though BeautifulSoup i noticed that HTML is not contains on text as you can see in below HTML:

```
<span class="js-posted">Posted
  <time data-eo-relative="2018-04-24T06:11:41+00:00" datetime="2018-0424T06:11:41+00:00" itemprop="datePosted"> </time> 
</span>
```

Can anyone tell me why the text is not showing in HTML? Why am I getting None value rather then the text exists?

Note: I'm using python 3.6.5 on window 10

Answer (score 1):

The site uses Javascript to show a relative time based on the attributes on the `<time>` element. You get `None` because BeautifulSoup does not load or execute Javascript code.

You could either extract the timestamp information from the attributes yourself, and make the same calculation, or you could use full headless browser to execute the page and extract the information afterwards. The [requests-html project](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/) could help you achieve the latter, but that seems overkill here.

Extracting the datetime attribute is trivial; the value is a ISO8601-formatted string so parsing it into a Python `datetime` object is easy enough too. If you *must* have a relative timestamp, subtract it from `datetime.now()` and format the resulting `datetime.timedelta()` object. Or use the [`humanize` library](https://pypi.org/project/humanize/) to create a nice 'human' relative time string, just like the site:

```
from datetime import datetime
import humanize

for elem in soup.select('.job-tile time["datetime"]'):
    # Python 3.6 %z only handles [+-]\d\d\d\d, not [+-]\d\d:\d\d, so remove
    # the last colon. Just hardcode the timezone, it's always UTC here anyway.
    dt_string = elem['datetime'].rpartition('+')[0] + '+0000'
    dt = datetime.strptime(dt_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
    local_naive = dt.astimezone().replace(tzinfo=None)  # local time, naive
    print('Posted', humanize.naturaltime(local_naive))
```

Once Python 3.7 is out, you can simply use `dt = datetime.fromisoformat(elem['datetime'])` and have the new [`datetime.fromisoformat()` class method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) handle the parsing for you.

For your input, this produces:

```
>>> for elem in soup.select('.job-tile time["datetime"]'):
...     dt_string = elem['datetime'].rpartition('+')[0] + '+0000'
...     dt = datetime.strptime(dt_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
...     local_naive = dt.astimezone().replace(tzinfo=None)  # local time, naive
...     print('Posted', humanize.naturaltime(local_naive))
...
Posted 8 minutes ago
Posted 35 minutes ago
Posted an hour ago
Posted an hour ago
Posted an hour ago
Posted an hour ago
Posted 2 hours ago
Posted 2 hours ago
Posted 2 hours ago
Posted 3 hours ago
```

Comment: i do same but facing error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 2, in <module>
    dt = datetime.strptime(elem['datetime'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
  File "C:\Python3\lib\_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2018-04-24T12:08:21+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'

Comment: @RashidAziz: ah, my apologies. I was using Python 3.7 and it contains a fix to handle the `:` in the `+00:00` timezone offset. In Python 3.6, only `+0000` is supported. I've updated the solution to avoid this problem altogether..